# Registration page of jomsocial edit

Tags: joomla-3.x, jomsocial

I'm working with Jomsocial on Joomla 3, and i want to edit the registration page of jomsocial.

So far, i've been able to locate the file, the view which shows the registration page, but i've been been able to fully edit it.

I want to place some elements/content by the side, and to also the edit the whole page.

How do i edit the view

Comment: Hi samson. Welcome to J.S.E. Could you give us more information. What file are you editing and what is and isn't working after the edit?

Answer (score 1):

**JomSocial** has its own templating system. Firstly, you have to create your own template, and duplicate the required files from the default template to customize the registration.

In this link, there is a nice detail of the required steps to customize a template and inspect the layout: http://documentation.jomsocial.com/wiki/Customizing_Template

Concerning to View classes, they are part of the distribution and they cannot be changed with an override.